# Understanding outstanding days with DATEDIFF, GETDATE

Tags: sql

- Is possible for my script code to return outstanding days on one column per `created_Date`?
- What I would like my code to do is, have the total days such as 90_days, 120_days, 180_days, 365_days, or, 1 year by the side of `Created_Date`.
- My query lists all data correctly per column name, however, I would like to see only one column displaying total days outstanding per `Created_Date` not all separate days outstanding with different headed columns.
- I have tried the following, and I get all the days separated on separate columns.

Example, this is what I meant:

```
______________________________________________________
Created_Date           |  Days Outstanding
2015-01-02 08:29:06    |  90-120
2015-01-02 08:35:44    |  90-120
2015-01-02 08:37:34    |  365
2015-01-02 09:07:01    |  120-180
2015-01-02 09:07:01    |  1 Year Plus
______________________________________________________
```

[Script Code:]

```sql
SELECT  DISTINCT ge.Name, 
     ge.Entity_Type, 
     ge.Entity_Number, 
     bc.Super_Entity_ID, 
     ch.Check_Date, 'Date check was requested
     ch.Created_Date, ' Created_Date was paid in full
     ch.Check_Number, 
     ch.Amount,
     vn.Vendor_Name,
     DATEDIFF(day, [Created_Date], Getdate()) as " Number of Days ",   ' Number 
     of Days Outstanding
     '90_days' = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, [Created_Date], Getdate()) Between  90 
     AND 120 Then [Amount] END, 
     '120_days' = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, [Created_Date], Getdate()) Between 120 
     AND 180 Then [Amount] END, 
     '180_plus' = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, [Created_Date], Getdate()) > 180 Then 
     [Amount] END
     FROM     
     dbo.gl_entities AS ge   ' All linked tables listed with "INNER JOIN"
     INNER JOIN
     dbo.super_entity AS se
     ON ge.Super_Entity_ID = se.Super_Entity_ID 
     INNER JOIN
     dbo.bank_codes AS bc
     ON se.Super_Entity_ID = bc.Super_Entity_ID 
     INNER JOIN
     dbo.checks AS ch
     ON bc.Bank_Code_ID = ch.Bank_Code_ID 
     INNER JOIN
     dbo.vendors AS vn
     ON ch.Vendor_ID = vn.Vendor_ID
     WHERE 
     DATEDIFF(Day, ch.Created_Date, GETDATE ()) > = 90 AND   
     ge.Active = 1 and vn.active = 1 and (ge.IS_Shadow = 1 OR se.IS_Tiered = 0)
     AND CHECK_DATE > '20150101 00:00:00'
     AND CHECK_DATE< '20190918 00:00:00'
     ORDER BY ch.Check_Date, ch.Created_Date
```

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single `CASE` expression, like:

```
CASE 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(day, [Created_Date], Getdate()) Between 90 AND 119 Then '90 days'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(day, [Created_Date], Getdate()) Between 120 AND 179 Then '90 days'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(day, [Created_Date], Getdate()) >= 180 Then '180+ days'
END As [Days Outstanding]
```